# Can I get A calendar to show a filtered and aggregate view

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, calendar

I would like to place a master calendar on the parent site and display it on
eleven subsites, using a filter to display relevant content. Can I do this? I
was looking at the content querry web part which displays links to the calendar
but I want a Calendar display or the calendar itself. 
The master calendar would display all calendar events, but each of the subsites would display only what a filer would tell them to.
For example The subsite , called "division x" would be filtered to only show "Division X" events (this would be taken from a dropdown). The home sites calendar would display all events.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it OOTB, because calendar doesn't accept incoming connections (!!). For a site, I had to do several views.

If you want to spend money, you can look at bamboo's Calendar Plus Web part.